# Writing $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ as union of closed intervals

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

"Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Set $A_k = A \cap [-k,k]^n$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Then we have $A = \bigcup_{l=1}^{\infty} A_l$." This decomposition is used often in proofs in a course on measure theory I am taking. However, I am not sure why the last equality is true. If $\mathbb{R}^n = \bigcup_{l=1}^{\infty} [-l,l]^n$, then it is obvious, as we then have $A = A \cap \mathbb{R}^n = A \cap \bigcup_{l=1}^{\infty} [-l,l]^n = \bigcup_{l=1}^{\infty}(A \cap [-l,l]^n) = \bigcup_{l=1}^{\infty} A_l$. Is $\mathbb{R}^n = \bigcup_{l=1}^{\infty} [-l,l]^n$ correct? I think  $\bigcup_{l=1}^{\infty} [-l,l]^n = [-\infty,\infty]^n$, which is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, $$\mathbb R^n=\bigcup_{\ell=1}[-\ell,\ell]^n,$$ is correct. Indeed, $[-\ell,\ell]^n\subset \mathbb R^n$ for all $\ell\in\mathbb N$. Therefore $$\bigcup_{\ell=1}^\infty [-\ell,\ell]^n\subset \mathbb R^n.$$

---

An other way to see this : $$\bigcup_{i\in \mathcal I}C_i=\{x\mid \exists i\in \mathcal I: x\in C_i\}.$$

So, to claim that $$[-\infty ,\infty ]=\bigcup_{\ell=1}^\infty [-\ell,\ell],$$
would mean that $$\pm\infty\in \bigcup_{\ell=1}^\infty [-\ell,\ell],$$
and thus that there exist $\ell\in \mathbb N$ s.t. $$\pm\infty \in[-\ell,\ell],$$
which is obviously wrong.